# Super prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was reading about super prime numbers in Wikipedia, nothing looks Unusual until i read this line.

> every integer greater than 96 may be represented as a sum of distinct super-prime numbers.

i thought that every number greater than 96 has a unique sum of this numbers, but it's not true.
so what this line exactly means ?

Comment: You might like to review [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/wiki/Higher-order_prime_numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement talks about *existence* of a representation, and not *uniqueness*. That is, it is possible that a number $>96$ can be represented in more than one way as a sum of super-primes; but it can't occur that there is no such representation.

(Don't know much about this subject; just interpreting what's written in Wikipedia.)